# Show tick labels when sharing an axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running the following function:

```
def plot_variance_analysis(indices, stat_frames, legend_labels, shape):
    x = np.linspace(1, 5, 500)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(shape[0], shape[1], sharex=True sharey=True)
    questions_and_axes = zip(indices, axes.ravel())
    frames_and_labels = zip(stat_frames, legend_labels)
    for qa in questions_and_axes:
        q = qa[0]
        ax = qa[1]
        for fl in frames_and_labels:
            frame = fl[0]
            label = fl[1]
            ax.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, frame['mean'][q], frame['std'][q]), label=label)
            ax.set_xlabel(q)
            ax.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xticks([1,2,3,4,5])
    return fig, axes
```

Here's what I get with some of my own sample data:

[image]

I'm trying to maintain the shared state between axes, but at the same time display the tick labels for the x axis on *all* subplots (including the top two). I can't find any means to turn this off in the documentation. Any suggestions? Or should I just set the x tick labels axis by axis?

I'm running matplotlib 1.4.0, if that's important.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In Matplotlib 2.2 and above the tick labels can be turned back on using:

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: `ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=True)` also works in `matplotlib==3.0.3`

Comment: if someone is searching for polar/radar chart, it is `ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=True)`

Comment: I found that when running a for loop in a jupyter notebook this has to occur in a separate for loop, after the initial for loop for creating the plots.

Answer (score 27):

The ticks that are missing have had their `visible` property set to `False`. This is pointed out in the documentation for `plt.subplot`. The simplest way to fix this is probably to do:

```
for ax in axes.flatten():
    for tk in ax.get_yticklabels():
        tk.set_visible(True)
    for tk in ax.get_xticklabels():
        tk.set_visible(True)
```

Here I've looped over all axes, which you don't necessarily need to do, but the code is simpler this way.  You could also do this with list comprehensions in an ugly one liner if you like:

```
[([tk.set_visible(True) for tk in ax.get_yticklabels()], [tk.set_visible(True) for tk in ax.get_yticklabels()]) for ax in axes.flatten()]
```

Comment: i wrapped this in a function and it worked exactly as shown above

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore. Any ideas on how to achieve this post matplotlib 2.0?

Comment: I haven't bothered checking 2.0, but in MPL 2.1.2 this does work. However, the ticklabels are visible on all axes by default. So, this trick should only be necessary for hiding the ticklabels with `tk.set_visible(False)`.

Comment: @MeshachBlue I am also using 2.0 and the above solution did not work for me. I tried tinkering with some things without any success; finally i ended up removing the `sharey` from my subplot creation and manually setting the `ylim`s for each axes to get the same y axis with the ticklabels.

Comment: I've also tried this in Matplotlib 2.2, and it doesn't seem to work. See below for a solution that does.

Answer (score 7):

You can find extra information about labels of matplotlib here:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html

In my case, I need to turn on all the x and y labels and this solution works:

```
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=True)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=True)
```