# Show y_ticklabels in a seaborn pairplot with shared axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn pairplot to plot several independent variables against a dependent variable.

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
x_vars = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length']
y_vars = ['petal_width']
pp = sns.pairplot(data=iris, x_vars=x_vars, y_vars=y_vars)
```

[image]

Now I want to add y axis ticks and labels to the second and third subplots.

Adding y axis labels is easy:

```
pp.set(ylabel='petal_width')
```

[image]

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to show the y_ticklabels.

Things like:

```
pp.set(yticklabels=np.arange(-0.5, 3.01, 0.5))
```

or:

```
for i in range(3):
    ax = pp.axes[0,i]
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-0.5, 3.01, 0.5))
    ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(-0.5, 3.01, 0.5))
    ax.set_visible(True)
```

make no difference.

Comment: `PairGrid` sets up the axes with `sharey=True` so the question here is really whether that can be turned off post-hoc.

Comment: @mwaskom, not really. The y ticks of the other subplots are just invisible. You can have shared y axes and still have the tick labels.

Comment: TIL that `share{x,y}` sets the visibility of the ticklabels!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just turn the `yticklabels` back to visible and you are good to go, in the desired subplot:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
x_vars = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length']
y_vars = ['petal_width']
pp = sns.pairplot(data=iris, x_vars=x_vars, y_vars=y_vars)
_ = plt.setp(pp.axes[0,1].get_yticklabels(), visible=True) #changing the 2nd plot
```

`_ = ...` here is to suppress unwanted print out in interactive environments.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

3.0.3 is my matplotlib version and [CT Zhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2487184/ct-zhu)'s answer didn't work for me and I don't know why.

I found the answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49670059/8757103)**.

You can use the `tick_params` method on your desired subplot to show the `yticklabels` by passing the `labelleft=True` parameter. (there are 2 ways)

---

```
"""enabling yticklabels for all subplots"""

import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
x_vars = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length']
y_vars = ['petal_width']
pp = sns.pairplot(data=iris, x_vars=x_vars, y_vars=y_vars)

# iterating over all subplots
for ax in pp.axes.flat:
    # labelleft refers to yticklabels on the left side of each subplot
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelleft=True) # method 1
    # ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=True) # method 2
plt.show()
```

---

[image: enabling yticklabels for shared axes]

From the `tick_params` [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html).

> Change the appearance of ticks, tick labels, and gridlines.

Answer (score 0):

Setting sharey to False, will give separate out the axes labels -
P.S - just sharing an example code from one of my use cases -

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15, 5), sharey=False)

fig.suptitle('Sentiment scores - comparison')

sns.countplot(df['Sentiment'], ax=ax[0])

sns.countplot(df['new_sentiment'], ax=ax[1])

fig.show()
```

The output looks as follows -

[image]