# matplotlib: Tick labels disappeared after set sharex in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, visible

When use `sharex` or `sharey` in subplots, the tick labels would disappeared, how to turn them back?
Here is an example just copied from the [official website](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/recipes/create_subplots.html):

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axs[0, 0].plot(x)

plt.show()
```

And we will see:
[image]

As we can see, the top-right plot doesn't have any tick labels, and others also lack some labels because of the axis was shared.
I think I should use something like `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Specifically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49670059/5851928) answer

Comment: that answer didn't work for me, no idea why.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `tick_params()` to design the plot:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for a in f.axes:
    a.tick_params(
    axis='x',           # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',       # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom=True,
    top=False,
    labelbottom=True)    # labels along the bottom edge are on

plt.show()
```